# Disable Draw Mode in OneNote when using the pencil

Tags: onenote

Is is possible to disable the "Draw mode" in OneNote?

I recently bought a Surface Go together with the Microsoft Pencil. I'm a heavy user of OneNote, but I don't need to make drawings the pencil. I just want to use the pencil in the same way as it behaves in other applications.

For example, I can use the pencil to scroll a web page up and down, left to right. In OneNote, I cannot do this, because, when it detects the finger, it automatically changes to the draw mode and instead of scrolling the page, it draws lines :(

Comment: This question is more about MS Office than programming. The question may be better asked at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) and tagged with the `microsoft-office` tag.

Comment: Thanks Pretasoc, I will post the question in SuperUser